# What's the best way to programmatically determine if a webcam is currently in use on a Windows 11 PC?

Tags: webcam

I saw a post from about five months ago asking how to determine if a webcam is present on a Windows machine, and a contributor by the name of Daniel B provided a great answer - using the pnputil command.

On the CLI example shared, I see the "Status" of the cameras listed as "Started".

Is there a parameter one can pass on the pnputil command to let you know if the camera is currently in active use?

I'm trying to find a way to create a virtual switch to trigger a home automation routine based on the status of my USB webcam on my desktop.

If my webcam is active, the "ON AIR" light outside my office turns on - when the webcab goes inactive, the light turns off.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In CMD, enter pnputil  to see list, including  pnputil /enum-devices /connected

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - that doesn't show if the camera is in use, just connected. A webcam can be connected without being "in use" :p